# ejabberd "mysql_conn: Received unknown signal, exiting" error

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I use ejabberd 2.1.12. It seems to work fine, but in logs I keep getting mysql connection errors. I thought that this is because of `mod_roster_odbc` (according i.e. to [this](http://www.ejabberd.im/node/3847) thread, but I disabled `mod_roster` and `mod_shared_roster` and nothing has changed).

I am on amazon EC2 on ubuntu 12.04. Errors are raised about 2 minutes after connecting some users to chat.

**UPDATE:** I have found some pattern here. When I connect few users (using adium), every few minutes there is few errors like that. This probably not depends on connected users count because it was the same for two and for eight connected users. Every error is one more mysql connection so if I get 5 errors I have 5 new connections, after a while it goes back to initial connections number.

Here is my log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-05-09 19:52:55 ===
E(<0.585.0>:ejabberd_odbc:552) : mysql_conn: Received unknown signal, exiting : {mysql_recv,
                                                                                 <0.586.0>,
                                                                                 closed,
                                                                                 normal}

=INFO REPORT==== 2013-05-09 19:52:55 ===
I(<0.585.0>:ejabberd_odbc:550) : Closing connection #Port<0.3454>: ok
```

**UPDATE2:** I traced mysql activity as giavac suggested and while ejabberd errors occurring I can see this in mysql logs:

```
130511  9:35:28    17 Connect   ejabberd@127.0.0.1 on
               17 Query use ejabberd
               17 Query set names 'utf8'
               18 Connect   ejabberd@127.0.0.1 on
               18 Query use ejabberd
               19 Connect   ejabberd@127.0.0.1 on
               18 Query set names 'utf8'
               19 Query use ejabberd
               19 Query set names 'utf8'
               20 Connect   ejabberd@127.0.0.1 on
               20 Query use ejabberd
               20 Query set names 'utf8'
```

I have no idea where does it come from and why does it cause error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Hey, yes it is running, it is accepting connections, every message I sent is in archive_messages table and it seems it doesn't affect conversations.

Comment: I'd trace the mysql activity: what do you see over port 3306?

Comment: Next direction I'd investigate is the life of connections to mysql. In other words, it may be that something is tearing down the TCP connection between ejabberd and mysql after some time of inactivity. Then, when new activity is required, ejabberd sets up a new connection because the previous existing ones have been torn down. If that's the case though you shouldn't see impacts on the correct behaviour?

Comment: Seems connection are being closed, most likely because of the socket being inactive.  In that case I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @Lucas , any chance you can share your ejabberd config file, part regarding archiving, I am not able to get it to work and there is hardly any documentation that could help

Comment: How did you fix it? I have same problem